# Why can't gulp-main-npm-files see angular-spinkit?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp, bower

I am trying to migrate away from bower, which is serving to get the front end vendor packages needed for a project. Currently, I am using the main-bower-files library to grab all of the libraries listed under "dependencies" in bower.json in a gulpfile.js. I am trying to use gulp-main-npm-files as a replacement.

To test this, I deleted angular-spinkit from bower.json and used npm-install --save. This created a new field in package.json, "dependencies", and placed the same version of angular-spinkit within. Moreover, the library now shows up in node_modules.

In gulpfile.js, I am trying to test whether this one change can work, and so far it has not.

```
gulp.task("build-vendor-src", function () {

var bower = gulp.src(

        mainBowerFiles("**/*.js", {

            "debugging": false,

            "overrides": {

                "angular-mocks": {ignore: true}

            }

        }))

    .pipe(devOnly(sourcemaps.init()))

    .pipe(uglify())

    .pipe(concat(buildProps.masterVendorJS))

    .pipe(devOnly(sourcemaps.write(".")))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildProps.distFolder));



var npm = gulp.src(

        mainNPMFiles(), {base:'./'})

    .pipe(devOnly(sourcemaps.init()))

    .pipe(uglify())

    .pipe(concat(buildProps.masterVendorJS))

    .pipe(devOnly(sourcemaps.write(".")))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildProps.distFolder));



return merge(bower, npm);

});
```

I keep getting this error in many place:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[INFO]  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-spinkit due to:

[INFO]  Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-spinkit' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

[INFO]  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=angular-spinkit
[INFO]      at http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:374
[INFO]      at http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:10245
[INFO]      at n (http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:9726)
[INFO]      at http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:10030
[INFO]      at http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:17679
[INFO]      at r (http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:825)
[INFO]      at h (http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:17527)
[INFO]      at http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:17696
[INFO]      at r (http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:825)
[INFO]      at h (http://localhost:9877dist/vendor.min.js:1:17527)
```

Comment: Have you added this to your module?

Comment: @AvneshShakya let's assume I didn't. How would I got about that?

Comment: @AvneshShakya If you meant to ask whether I placed the library as a dependency in the angularJS itself, as in var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angular-spinkit']), then yes.